# Jquery Validation when all enabled fileds are not empty

Tags: jquery

Please help me to do the following using JQuery.

Condition 1: How can I check if all fields(input, textarea, select) that are **enabled** are not empty or has a selected value.

Condition 2: The fields that are **disabled are not included in the validation on condition 1.**

Ive already tried a lot of codes and the code below seems will do, but it captures all fields including those are disabled.

```
$('#btnSave').click(function (e) {
    $('input:enabled:not([readonly])').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "")
        {
            alert("Please fill out all fields.");
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            addSomeStuffs();
        }
    });
 });
```

Can anyone will help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your generated/final markup in the question, too?

Comment: Use Jquery Validate option. Its adding a "Required" Class to the fields which is available in the form. the link "https://jqueryvalidation.org/" will give you some idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery Form validation will help you in achieving your requirement

https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your selectors, and your logic is *almost* correct. What went wrong in your original code is that `addSomeStuffs()` will be executed as long as a non-empty input is encountered before an empty one.

What you want to do is:

1. Set a flag, let's call it `invalid`. It will be set to false whenever one or more fields are empty
2. Iterate through your input elements. If one of them is empty, set `invalid = true` and exit the loop (since we do not need to go any further, because the form is already invalid and nothing can change that)
3. After the loop, evaluate the `invalid` boolean. If it is false (i.e. all fields are valid), then we call `addMoreStuff()`

See a proof-of-concept example below:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btnSave').click(function(e) {
  
    // Invalid flag
    var invalid = false;

    // Iterate through all inputs
    $('input:enabled:not([readonly])').each(function() {
    
      // As long as one field is empty, we exit the loop and change invalid to true
      if ($(this).val() === "") {
        invalid = true;
        console.log('One or more fields are empty');
        console.log('First encountered invalid field: ', this);
        return false;
      }
      
    });
    
    // Evaluate invalid flag after iteration
    if (!invalid)
      addSomeStuffs();
  });
  
  var addSomeStuffs = function() {
    console.log('Validation passed');
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label>Text input: <input type="text" placeholder="Text" /></label><br />
  <label>Text input: <input type="text" placeholder="Text" /></label><br />
  <label>Disabled text input: <input type="text" placeholder="Text" disabled /></label>
  <label>Select: <select><option>---Choose an option below---</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select></label>
  <button type="button" id="btnSave">Save</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#btnSave').click(function (e) {
 var empty = false;
 $('form > input').each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        empty = true;
    }
 });

 if (empty) {
    alert("Please fill out all fields.");
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
 } else {
    addSomeStuffs();
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

theres nothing wrong with your code. you were just missed the `[type=text]` attribute in `input` to validate only `text field`. also remove `return false;` if you want to `count` the empty `fields`.

```
$('#btnSave').click(function (e) {
    $('input[type=text]:enabled:not([readonly])').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "")
        {
            alert("Please fill out all fields.");
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            addSomeStuffs();
        }
    });
 });
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/awtszs/qkgr0x1h/6/)